# How do I get Zune software to save my photos in My Pictures?

Tags: windows-7, sync, photos, zune-software

In Windows 7, I have two folders in my Pictures library:

1. My Pictures (C:\Users\Me)
2. Public Pictures (C:\Users\Public)

The My Pictures folder is the default save location.  Both of those folders are listed in the Zune settings, but when syncing my phone, it saves all my photos and videos in Public Pictures, which is not what I want. How do I get them to be saved in My Pictures instead?

Comment: are you using a Windows Phone for this? Windows Phone and Zune are the only two physical devices that can sync with the Zune software.

Comment: I am using a Windows Phone.  It syncs, it's just that it syncs to the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

List item

- Go to settings
- Collection
- Click on Manage in the Pictures section
- Set the default save location.

Comment: I already did this but it still didn't change where the pictures were saved.